# Telerik Extensions for MVC grid OnRowSelect problem

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik Extensions for ASP .Net MVC grid on my web page and, even though I've added the "Selectable" method to it, the OnRowSelect event is not getting triggered. It seems that the grid is not even responding to the "Selectable" method since my mouse pointer does not change to the hand when I'm hovering over the grid.

Here is the grid declaration:

```
<% Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Students)
       .Name("Students")
       .DataKeys(keys =>
            keys.Add(s => s.Id)   
        )
       .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(s => s.CourseScore).ReadOnly();
            columns.Bound(s => s.StudentName).ReadOnly();
            columns.Bound(s => s.Points).ReadOnly();
            columns.Template(s =>
            {%>
                <input name="GradeReleaseStatus" type="checkbox" value="<%=s.GradeRelease%>"
                <%if (s.GradeRelease)
                {%>
                    checked="checked"
                <%}%>
                />
                <%
            }).Title("Release Grade");
        })
        .Selectable()
        .ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowSelect("Activities.DisplaySingleGrade"))
        .Render(); %>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see a hover effect when you move the mouse over a grid row? If yes - then selection is working. If not - probably there is a JavaScript error in your page. If you don't see a JavaScript error make sure the grid initialization JavaScript is output. This needs a ScriptRegistrar component to be present *after* the grid declaration. Lastly you can try with a simpler script to see if the JavaScript event is raised:

```
events.OnSelect("onSelect")


<script>
 function onSelect() {
    alert("OnSelect");
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Atanas. The ScriptRegistrar call was on the head section of my master page. By moving it to the end of its body the grid started working as expected. Having the scripts there causes a different set of problems though, but at least this specific issue is resolved.